# How to make a running application visible to everyone

Tags: google-app-engine

I've been tinkering around with a google application engine application for a couple weeks, and I can't figure out how to remove the permission requirements (or make it permissions open to all).  Can anyone point me in the direction of the right configuration I need to change?

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you want, and show your `yaml` or `xml` config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most like it's because you forgot to set the "login" setting to "optional", or simply remove the key altogether, for the request handler in your. See here for more details: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status